# How can I append a string to a dynamic number value via preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string inside another to which I need to append something.

The structure of string is something like this:

```
$output = "Family: peppers, dimensions: 150 cm, origin: South America, Pot diameter: 14, height with pot: 80";
```

In that string I need to find `Pot diameter` and append to its numeric value the string `cm`. so it will look like

```
Pot diameter: 14 cm.
```

In the site it appears like this:

```
Family: peppers.
Dimensions: 150cm
Origin: South America
Pot diameter: 14
Height with pot: 80
```

I have been trying to use `preg_replace()` via

```
$output = preg_replace("/Pot diameter: [0-9]+/", '\0 cm.', $output)
```

but it doesn't work at all. I can't figure out how to find a number within given string - an exact number won't work because it's used dynamically. Only letters inside this string are static.

I figure out that Source code shows:

```
<div><br/>
<b>Średnica doniczki: </b>
14<br/>
</div>
```

Changing to:

```
$output = preg_replace("/<b>Średnica doniczki: </b> <br/>[0-9]+/", '\0 cm.', $output);
```

Dosen't work either.

I have now solution

```
$output = preg_replace("/<b>Średnica doniczki: <\/b>(.*?)<\/div>/", 'Średnica doniczki: $1 cm.</div>', $output);
```

I just picked the next closing tag, and find anything between given string and ending tag, and then just inject the same string with first taken value and it works as i wanted to do.

Comment: The matching is case-sensitive. You've got `pot` in the string and `Pot` in the function, so it doesn't match. You also need `$` instead of `%` for a variable name in PHP. Fix that and it works fine - demo: https://3v4l.org/mpCvp . Voting to close this question as a typo, because those issues are trivial and have nothing to do with the question supposedly being asked.

Comment: P.S. See also [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help you with the presentation of your future questions and answers. Thanks.

Comment: Those are just misspellings, variables and letter case have no matter here. Preg_replace just seems like it dosen't see that string. Here is site where i'm trying to prepend

https://e-botanica.pl/p/rhaphidophora-decursiva-dragon-tail/

Here is exacly what im trying to do:
$output = preg_replace("/Średnica doniczki: [0-9]+/", '\0 cm.', $output);
And it dosen't add it at all

Comment: I just showed you a demo of your code working when you fix the letter case.

Comment: It also works with the text you've just provided: https://3v4l.org/ZA7Rr

Comment: There is no input string, this all is on that one variable. Letter case has no matter as I just were saying. That was misspelling, that's all.
String is prepending dynamically via functions i want to inject it in middle of its opperations. And prepend to it. Others operations i made like changing tags etc has been worked, but i can't figure out how to work with it as this way. Code seems like it should work, but it dosen't.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/ZA7Rr shows it working with `Średnica doniczki`. Did you look? It seems like what you showed us is working already. You'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue before we can help you...right now we don't have that. Perhaps you need to debug your code more in case the real issue is elsewhere, preventing you from seeing the result.

Comment: I know, i just figure out that source code shows diffrent, so it should containts tags inside that string actually. I will try fix it by myself then

Comment: There's no `<br/>` before the 14 in your example, but there is a newline (`\n`). https://3v4l.org/us258 looks like it would be the solution

Comment: Ok i figure it out: I just taken the next closing tag and just inject entire row within it like this.

$output = preg_replace("/<b>Średnica doniczki: <\/b>(.*?)<\/div>/", 'Średnica doniczki: $1 cm.</div>', $output);
It replaces and inject the number and now works i wanted it to do.
Thank you for your help ADyson, your tips where precious to me.

Comment: It's great that you figured it out, but you need to give the answer properly. fullCalendar is a Question and Answer site. If you have a solution it must be put in the Answers section below - not in the comments, and not in your original question. The answer is not part of the question! Your answer can then be searched and voted on separately. Without an Answer recorded, other people with similar issues will not see this post in search results because it appears not to have any answers or solutions. Please also take the [tour] if you're unfamiliar with how Stackoverflow is structured. Thanks.

Comment: [Some other idea](https://regex101.com/r/nwyFCa/1) by use of `\K` (reset start of reported match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem via

```
$output = preg_replace("/<b>Średnica doniczki: <\/b>(.*?)<\/div>/", 'Średnica doniczki: $1 cm.</div>', $output);
```

To do so I just picked the next closing tag,
In the next step I find anything between given string and ending tag,
Next I just inject the same string what is given with first taken value and closing tag
And now it works as i wanted to do.